# Test Class for Contact

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a code that is testing a batch, I am creating a contact and an Account , but the contact isn't getting linked to the account (c.AccountId = null). The same code is tested in Async window and it is creating a contact linked to an account.

```
    Account account = new Account();
    account.RecordType = AccountUtilities.RecordTypes.get('Corporate_Golden_Record');
    account.Name = 'test corp';
    account.phone= '01123123';
    account.billingcity='London';
    account.billingpostalcode='SW1635HJ';
    account.billingcountry='United Kingdom';
    account.billingstreet='address 1';
    account.retailer_email__c= 'corp@test1223.com';
    insert account;


    //Insert contact for Account
    Contact c = new Contact();
    c.AccountId = account.ID;
    c.FirstName = 'test';
    c.LastName = 'test';
    c.email = 'test@test.com';
    c.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Contact').getRecordTypeId();
    c.Language__c = 'EN';
    c.birthdate = Date.newInstance(1992, 04, 12);
    insert c;


    system.debug('-- Contact : ' + c.Account.Name);
    system.debug('-- Contact : ' + c.ID);

    Test.startTest();
    ...
    Test.stopTest();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only value that gets updated in the Apex instance for any SObject when you insert is the Id value. Other fields populated as part of the insert by triggers or other logic have to be re-queried to get the values.

The immediate field value will be available just after insert in test class for contact object but in order to access the parent record value you need to re-query the inserted record.

for e.g. If you check **account.Name** you will get the value but when you will try to get **c.Account.Name** you need to re query the contact record.